# Indenting text in HTML

Tags: html, css, indentation, spacing

I'm trying to figure out spacing in CSS and a way to move text relative to the center of a page.

if you know a way in CSS to do this, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Cant comment yet, so can you please give us ur html markup and css u use?
on case you dont know how to do that at all, here is a jsfiddle example:
[jsfiddle.com/ux37xq6m](http://jsfiddle.net/ux37xq6m/)

```
<table id="demo_table">
  <tr>
    <td id="left">Left side</td>
    <td id="right">Right one</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: for now they're just two pieces of text in one div (like 
`<div><span>item1</span><span>item2</span>
</div>`)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use absolute positioning and just specify the right offset to 25% (or left to 75%). Add a class to "Item 2" with the following CSS:

```
.right-middle{
    position:absolute;
    right:25%;
}
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ypk4hkvw/